# Made my password a few characters over the 64 character count and can't mount

Tags: disk-encryption, veracrypt

I can't enter my full password here (the screenshot) since veracrypt limits character count to 64 and my pass is 66. Is the data on the drive recoverable?

[image: veracryptbox]

Comment: Try commandline: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20Line%20Usage

Comment: Did you try just using the first 64 characters?

Comment: It's open source, find the code that limits the input, change and recompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you make a password that's "too long" for a system, what actually happens is that it gets truncated to the system's max length, then hashed, and the result of the hashing function(s) is used for authentication purposes.

Therefore, the general approach to getting access when you created a password that's too long is to truncate the password yourself.  In this case, your password is likely to be the first 64 characters of what you chose as your password, based on veracrypt's max password length.